# FCITX Chinese-Black box appears instead of character options

Tags: screen, input, chinese, fcitx, shadow

Recently started having problems with the native pinyin input. It was working fine, then this week it stopped showing options for chinese characters. Instead, there is just a much larger black box. I switched between compton and macro as windows manager. Using Macro it just did not offer any character options, but no black box.

Attempted to uninstall `fcitx-ui-qimpanel`. It did not help. Re-installing also did not change anything.

Ubuntu Mate 16.04

[image: black box]